# VLC specifying audio device on command line on Windows?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I tried the following command, to play an audio file on vlc that plays on the monitor speaker, instead of the default speaker that plays on my audio interface.

```
vlc.exe --qt-start-minimized --alsa-audio-device "LG IPS FULLHD" "Windows Notify System Generic.wav" vlc://quit
// Note that I also tried --alsa-audio-device "Default"
```

But it gets an error message.

```
vlc media player could not start
vlc either the command line options were invalid or no plugins were found
```

What can I do to play a file on vlc specifying the audio output device on Windows? Thanks.